# How does `conda activate` change *current* bash environment?

Tags: python, bash, shell, environment-variables, conda

If I want to change my current bash env variables by executing a shell script, I need to do `source somecript`, so that the env setting commands are run in current bash rather than a forked one.

`conda` itself is a python script, and by just running `conda activate someenv` on the command line, bash itself is forked first. If that is the case, how come after execution of this command, my original bash env variable were set?

I tried to dig into the conda package but wan't able to find how this is done before getting lost...

Comment: When a child process starts it inherits from the parent. I don't know if this answers your questions but it's good to know.

Comment: Yes, but the question here was about how come a parent's env is seemingly modified by a child. But as @FlyingTeller pointed out, `conda` here is actually a function, so no child is involved in this case at all.

Comment: FWIW, [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62015/running-an-executable-in-path-with-the-same-name-as-an-existing-function) explores the issue of shell functions shadowing commands. In case anyone uses `which conda` and get confused like I did.. `type -a conda` would've been a better tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> conda itself is a python script

I don't know where you have read this. `conda` is set up as a bash function, which you can verify yourself. In the `.bashrc` you can see that the file `/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh` is called to set up the `conda` command, which looks like this:

```
conda() {
    if [ "$#" -lt 1 ]; then
        "$CONDA_EXE" $_CE_M $_CE_CONDA
    else
        \local cmd="$1"
        shift
        case "$cmd" in
            activate|deactivate)
                __conda_activate "$cmd" "$@"
                ;;
            install|update|upgrade|remove|uninstall)
                CONDA_INTERNAL_OLDPATH="${PATH}"
                __add_sys_prefix_to_path
                "$CONDA_EXE" $_CE_M $_CE_CONDA "$cmd" "$@"
                \local t1=$?
                PATH="${CONDA_INTERNAL_OLDPATH}"
                if [ $t1 = 0 ]; then
                    __conda_reactivate
                else
                    return $t1
                fi
                ;;
            *)
                CONDA_INTERNAL_OLDPATH="${PATH}"
                __add_sys_prefix_to_path
                "$CONDA_EXE" $_CE_M $_CE_CONDA "$cmd" "$@"
                \local t1=$?
                PATH="${CONDA_INTERNAL_OLDPATH}"
                return $t1
                ;;
        esac
    fi
}
```

and calls the `__add_sys_prefix_to_path` function to modify the PATH:

```
__add_sys_prefix_to_path() {
    # In dev-mode CONDA_EXE is python.exe and on Windows
    # it is in a different relative location to condabin.
    if [ -n "${_CE_CONDA}" ] && [ -n "${WINDIR+x}" ]; then
        SYSP=$(\dirname "${CONDA_EXE}")
    else
        SYSP=$(\dirname "${CONDA_EXE}")
        SYSP=$(\dirname "${SYSP}")
    fi

    if [ -n "${WINDIR+x}" ]; then
        PATH="${SYSP}/bin:${PATH}"
        PATH="${SYSP}/Scripts:${PATH}"
        PATH="${SYSP}/Library/bin:${PATH}"
        PATH="${SYSP}/Library/usr/bin:${PATH}"
        PATH="${SYSP}/Library/mingw-w64/bin:${PATH}"
        PATH="${SYSP}:${PATH}"
    else
        PATH="${SYSP}/bin:${PATH}"
    fi
    \export PATH
}
```

so `conda` doesn't launch any sub bash shells, but is just a (series) of bash functions, which simply edit the current env variable in place

Comment: cool. I thought `conda` was a bash script because `which conda` told me so... Apparently `which` only looks for executables in `$PATH`, and `type` can identify functions and more. Also, bash functions takes precedents over executables with the same name.

Comment: Some additional details: the default install sets up shell functions via code that is generated on the fly with `conda shell.bash hook` and is evaluated when shell initialization files (e.g., `.bashrc`) are sourced. The `conda.sh` file is a fallback and usually is never run. Nevertheless, most Conda functionality is Python (the `which conda` points to the entry point); it is only `conda activate`, which manages environment switching and mostly involves editing environment variables, that is shell code.